# PDF-Shuffler | Cannot save a changed PDF-file

Tags: pdf

After rotating some pages using PDF-Shuffler, I couldn't save the pdf-file and got the following massage:

**Multiple definitions in dictionary at byte 0x8b3dfc for key /PageMode**

Do you have any idea, how to fix this?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my previos question. The problem was, that my pdf-file (a book) couldn't be changed due to some security options (password).

I've just tried to print the pdf into the file. Then, I saw, that the document became changable. So, now I can rotate or move several pages inside the document and save it again.

Solved!!! ;)